# How to intercept a download request on puppeteer and read the file being intercepted

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer for web scraping, i need to setup a request interception to read a file that is being downloaded from the browser without actually downloading it because it takes a lot of resources to download read and then delete it.

I have already identified the request, but found no way to read from it

```
await pages[0].setRequestInterception(true);
  pages[0].on('request', request => {
    if (request.resourceType() === 'font' || request.resourceType() === 'stylesheet' || request.resourceType() === 'image') {
      request.abort();
    } else {
      request.continue();
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rather use the [response](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#event-response) event because the request interception doesn't have the response yet.

```js
pages[0].on('response', async response => {
    if (response.request() /*Your condition check*/) {
      var buffer = await response.buffer(); /*You can get the buffer*/
      var content = await response.text(); /*You can get the content as text*/
    }
});
```

Comment: you missed an `async` in your code, can't await in callback with async

Comment: Is it possible to read the file but prevent it from actually downloading?

Comment: No. You could intercept the request (as you are doing now) and then perform a manual fetch to that URL.